# Can't push on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I’ve just cloned one of my repositories on github, I've made some changes and I would like to send it on the heroku application. But when I try to run `git push heroku master`, I get :

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Have you re-pushed to Github? Also run `git remote -v` to ensure you are pushing to the right Heroku repo

Comment: yes I've re pushed to github. and remote -v gave me that :
origin  myaccount/vitrine.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/grosalex/vitrine.git (push)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there's no remote named heroku. You can see your remotes by typing `git remote -v`. For my 'example' app I see the following:

```
$ git remote -v
heroku git@heroku.com:example.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:example.git (push)
```

If it's missing, you can add the remote with the following command:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:example.git
```

where example is the name of your heroku app.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can do

```
$ git push heroku master
```

you need to setup heroku by following the steps given at [Getting Started with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart). Once you have setup heroku, logged in,created your app.

Verify that git remote is added

```
$ git remote -v
```

it should list a remote named `heroku`. if it does then the error `heroku' does not appear to be a git repository` will go away

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the steps in tutorial you just need to login in again:

```
cmd "heroke login"
```